# vba button - find which was clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I have assigned macro to few buttons.

How can I find out inside macro which button was clicked?

I am doing as user form, where he can input peoples from family:

*name1:

surname1:*

*name2:

surname2:*                **|add next member|**

I wish button to appear always in last row of the last added person.
For simplicity I think it is better to have like 100 empty forms in the 
sheet but all invisible at the begining.
Then when user clicks add next member I simply make next rows visible,
and move button to next person. But to do that I need to know my current position.

Similar with deletion I would make rows invisible when remove  button is clicked.

*name1:

surname1:*         **[remove]**

*name2:

surname2:*         **[remove]**

*name3:

surname3:*                **|add next member|**

I need to know which remove button was clicked.

**EDIT:** 
Found in web - what do you think, seems to be best /way

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Select
```

Comment: So to clarify your edit, it appears that you only have one set of buttons, but you keep moving them.  So all you really need to know is how to position buttons in a row.  Is that it?

Comment: I number of "remove" buttons, and at the very and "add" button.

Comment: OK, I found how to get the button, but it looks like you already found it.  You can simplify the Select statement but it looks fine.

Comment: last line simplify to `R.SELECT`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I always write wrappers for each button that then call the macro in question.

Like so:

```
Public Sub StoreButton_Click()

  Call StoreTransValues(ActiveSheet)

End Sub
```

If you have only one button for any one page, you can just get the ActiveSheet property, and it will be the button on that page.

---

**Edit:**

Here's the code to get and use the name of the calling button:

```
Dim ButtonText As String

ButtonText = Application.Caller

ActiveSheet.Shapes(ButtonText).Delete
```

You would use the .Move method to move the button.

Comment: I can not simply adapt your proposal for my case. I still need to find out what is position of clicked button, then find which row it is, and finally remove all e.g. 2 rows above.

Answer (score 11):

I finally found the solution for determining which button in a Worksheet was pushed.  Credit is due to Derk at http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33351.

My final example code:

```
Sub HereIAm()
    Dim b As Object
    Dim cs, rs As Integer
    Dim ss, ssv As String
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        rs = .Row
        cs = .Column
    End With
    ss = Left(Cells(1, cs).Address(False, False), 1 - (ColNumber > 26)) & rs
    ssv = Range(ss).Value
    MsgBox "Row Number " & rs & "    Column Number " & cs & vbNewLine & _
        "Cell " & ss & "   Content " & ssv
End Sub
```

If you don't need the cells label, Cells(rs,cs).Value works as well.

Comment: ActiveSheet returns a worksheet object. A worksheet object does not have a property called "Buttons". How can this work?

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim button as a string:

    button = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a macro wired to your button(s), I assume you know which button it is that was clicked. To get the location of the button, use this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ButtonName").TopLeftCell.Address
```

To move a button to a new location, use this:

```
Dim NewAddress as Range
NewAddress = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 5) 'Or where ever you need it to go
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ButtonName").Left = NewAddress.Left
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ButtonName").Top = NewAddress.Top
```

Comment: not if you simplify the code by assigning the same macro to each button, in wich case the macro neeeds to be smarter

Comment: Got the position with your answer and placed it with http://stackoverflow.com/a/8303944/2932994