# Place a command button in a cell MS Excel vba

Tags: vba, button, excel, activex

I want to place a command button in a cell though VBA code. Say position B3. I used macro recorder for this purpose but it gives me the top bottom values of the button. I don't want that cuz if I take my code to some other computer with another screen resolution, the code will fail. A cell position (example B3) will be an absolute position.

Can you suggest me a way to do this.

P.S Its an activeX button

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't place any object "in" a cell, only over it. You can set the button's Left and Top properties to the Cell's Left/Top.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton1")
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Width = rng.Width
        .Height = rng.RowHeight
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

***An Alternative to "putting a button in a cell"***

Make a cell selection execute code, directly, using the worksheet event: `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.  Place the code in the specific sheet's module.  Color/Border/Text the cell as you please.  A cell-is-a-cell on any computer or screen.  I use this to reference help loaded into a userForm, from a look up on a help sheet, when the user clicks on a short label/description.   Using cell/buttons avoids Active-X objects complaints from IT.

Things to think on, with the sample code, following:

1. Target.Address returns absolute addresses, using the "$" character
2. Use the `Select Case` in your code, even if you have one cell/button.  This eases the path to adding cell/buttons, later
3. consider using named ranges on the spreadsheet, and reference them in the code.  That way, VBA won't care if you move the cell/button
4. If you have merged cells for which you create a named range, remember that the named range, in the spreadsheet, only points to the top-left cell

   - However, the `Target.Address` for the merged area returns the full range, not just one cell.  If your `Select Case` refers to the address of the `Target`'s top-left cell, you avoid this problem.
   - use `Target.Cells(1,1).Address`
5. Bad choice for merged cells: don't use `MergeArea.Address` (`MergeArea` will not work on merged cells [only works on single cells]; it returns the merged range within which a cell lives.

**Sample Code**

```
'How to Make Cells into Buttons that execute code
' place code in the specific Worksheet module of interest
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   ' in this example, I create named ranges on the spreadsheet '
            ' [complicated names, here, so you can read what's what]:
      ' one cell:  "Button_OneCellNameRange"
      ' one set of merged cells:  "Button_MergedCellNameRange"
         ' [the reference is the top-left cell, only]

   ' a VBA created cell/button location [not very useful for later sheet edits]
      Dim myVBACellButton As Range
      Set myVBACellButton = Range("B2")

         Debug.Print "Target Address: " & Target.Address
               'merged cells will return a range: eg "$A$1:$D$3"

         Debug.Print "Target.Cells(1,1).Address: " & Target.Cells(1, 1).Address
               'merged cells will return the top left cell, which would match
                  ' a named reference to a merged cell
   Select Case Target.Cells(1, 1).Address
        'if you have merged cells, you must use the ".cells(1,1).address"
        ' and not just Target.Address

      Case Is = "$A$1"
         MsgBox "Hello from: Click on A1"

      Case Is = myVBACellButton.Address
         MsgBox "Hello from: Click on B2, a VBA referenced cell/button"
            ' "myCellButton" defined as range in VBA

      'using a range named on the spreadsheet itself ...
         ' named ranges allow one to move the cell/button freely,
         ' without VBA worries
      Case Range("Button_OneCellNameRange").Address
         MsgBox "Hello From: Button Click on Button_OneCellNameRange"

      Case Range("Button_MergedCellNamedRange").Address
         'note that the address for merged cells is ONE CELL, the top left
         MsgBox _
            "Hello from: Button_MergedCellNamedRange.Address: " _
                  & Range("Button_MergedCellNamedRange").Address _

      Case Else ' normally you wouldn't be using this, for buttons
         MsgBox "NOT BUTTONS"

   End Select
End Sub
```

[image: Image of the Sheet]