# How do you assign different macros to each command button at the top of each column so that they work independantly from the other macros?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have assigned the following macro to the first column of my spread sheet to sort the information in ascending and descending order. This macro is assigned to the command button and works.

```
If CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to Sort Ascending" Then

'Sort ascending...
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A308"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:Z308")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to Sort Decending"

Else

'sort decending
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A308") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("daily data drop").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:Z308")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to Sort Ascending"

End Sub
```

I would like to have all the top headers of each column to have a button that sorts ascending and descending like the macro above, in keeping the row data matched up. Can any one help me with this or have a template that may be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place a command button in a cell MS Excel vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303887/place-a-command-button-in-a-cell-ms-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to place a button on each column. I will suggest a method that does not need buttons at all. Moreover, you should always avoid to duplicate large parts of your code, where only one or two statements differ according to some parameter. You should always try to "factorize" your code and shorten it as much as possible, which makes it more readable and maintainable.

A possible way to achieve your goal would be that the user "double-clicks" on the header cell and have the data sorted by the clicked column. And after each sort, the sorting order is reversed.

You can do that by adding the following handler to  the code-module of your worksheet `"daily data drop"`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Static descending As Boolean
    If Target.Row <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    Me.UsedRange.Sort Target, IIf(descending, xlDescending, xlAscending), Header:=xlYes
    descending = Not descending
End Sub
```