# Inserting a button into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that populates a row of cells with the user's input. The last cell in the row contains a button that, when clicked, should move that row to another sheet and remove it from the first sheet. I can't work out how to link the button to that cell to give it a reference point so that I can tell it which row to move.

Currently, the button is positioned in the cell `t`, as below.

```
        Set t = ws.Cells(2, 1).Offset(j, 10)
        Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

        With btn
            .OnAction = "Printed"
            .Caption = "Complete"
            .Name = "btn" & j
        End With
```

Is there any way to assign the button to a cell? Or activate the cell behind the button when clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the row number in the button name, and access it in your macro using Application.Caller

Comment: @TimWilliams I thought about this, but I believe I'll run into some trouble later on. The buttons are named "btn j" with j being the respective row number. However since the button removes a row, this will cause the next row that is added to have the same button name as the previous row. That make sense? I probably didn't explain myself very well.

Comment: A search in SO for "place a command button in a cell" will help you create a macro to put a button in a cell. 
You will also have to assign a macro Sub Button1_Click() to copy your data to the other worksheet.

Comment: @GMalc59 I have scoured the internet for hours and unfortunately haven't found anything. I have already positioned the button in a cell, but I am more looking for a way to activate the cell that the button is in when clicked.

Comment: In Stack Overflow type in the search box "place a command button in a cell"@TimWilliams provides a very good macro to put a button in a cell.
You don't need to activate the cell below the button, just assign a macro for when you click the button.

Comment: You'll need to have/create some sort of unique identifier on each row that you can tie the button to.  Or (better I think) use a hyperlink to trigger the move/delete: then you don't need to worry about acting on the correct row.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hyperlink is a great idea. Thank you!

Comment: I would have a preset button with it's macro to move the row of activecell, but had it hidden until user clicks the appropriate range generated by the userform? Use the Worksheet_SelectionChange event to move, relocate the button.

Comment: Useful method here for running a method from a hyperlink 
 (see lori_m's answer ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660492/running-vba-from-a-hyperlink/32662063#32662063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place a button in a cell. As you can see from your code, the button is placed not in a cell but on the sheet. Its position on the sheet is defined by the location of the cell relative to which the button was positioned.

You can reverse this process. `Btn.TopLeftCell` specifies a `Range`, a cell to be precise, where the top-left corner of the button is located. That range has a `Row` property which is the row number you are interested in. It may be presumed that the `TopLeftCell` of your button will be the cell relative to which you first created it. However, since you can move buttons freely across the sheet that is not a given.

Note that `Btn.TopLeftCell.Top` returns the position of the cell itself on the sheet. Therefore you can set the button's `Top` property equal to its `TopLeftCell.Top` property to achieve alignment programmatically. Do the same with the `Left`.

Comment: @What a Dave: this answer gives you the clues you need. Get the row you want to move (Btn.TopLeftCell.Row), move the row, then move the button (Btn.Top = Btn.TopLeftCell.Row.Offset(-1,0).Top).

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted using `Btn.TopLeftCell`. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303944/7955781

Short: You can't bind any Object into a Cell, only over it. "You can set the button's Left and Top properties to the Cell's Left/Top.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton1")
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Width = rng.Width
        .Height = rng.RowHeight
    End With
End Sub
```

"