# Automatically resize a pasted image to the size of the cell it's being pasted in to

Tags: excel, vba, image, resize, paste

I have to paste chart images generated from a non microsoft program to an excel sheet. I use snipping tool and paste into excel. Unfortunately the images are nowhere near the size they need to be. The cells being pasted to are static in location and size. I cant seem to figure how to resize the image as its pasted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
    
        ' ResizeImage1 Macro
        Range("A3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=2
        Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.5787264566, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.6271851817, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

This dosen't work at all.

I also tried this from stack overflow and it dosnt work either

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


'Image Script

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column L has changed
On Error GoTo 0
     'paste excel table as enhanced metafile, then resize to full width

    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth ActiveCell.Width, _
    msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight ActiveCell.Height, _
    msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft


    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Pasting onto a sheet doesn't trigger a `Change` event.  The typical approach would be to set the pasted shape's .Top, .Left, .Height and .Width properties.  Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303944/478884 only you're working with a Shape and not a button.