# How to pass the value of the Date Picker to a macro through the "Assign Macro..." window?

Tags: vba

(SW versions: Excel 2010 - Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP4))

In the sheet "sheet1" I have an ActiveX Date Picker control calendar named "foobarCalendar".
Next to it I put a button and in its "Assign Macro..." I want to specify a macro with as argument the date of this calendar "foobarCalendar".

In VBA I can get this date with "sheet1.foobarCalendar", however I'm unable to find any working way to put this as argument in the "Assign Macro..." window.

Is there a working syntax or it's simply not possible?

(another problem I encounter is that my macro name doesn't appear on the list, but I discovered that it's because Excel only display the macroes that don't get arguments in this list, although I can manually write them and use them successfully)

I tried for example 'macroName sheet1.foobarCalendar' but it's not working.
I also tried many other syntax, including those that work for passing named ranges and including the "evaluate" variants, without success.  Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't pass arguments from there, you will need to get the value from inside the macro itself.

Comment: A macro assigned to a control (CommandButton, in this case) can't have a parameter. But you have two options:  1) hard-code the handling of your date picker control into your macro so it doesn't need a parameter, or 2) in the macro, [determine which button was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3858067/4717755) and act accordinginly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In VBA I can get this date with "sheet1.foobarCalendar", however I'm unable to find any working way to put this as argument in the "Assign Macro..." window.*

You don't. `Sheet1.foobarCalendar` is already in scope: have the macro use it.

```
Public Sub MyMacro()
    Dim workingDate As Date
    workingDate = Sheet1.foobarCalendar
    '...
End Sub
```

That said, [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29858176/1188513) a way to invoke a parameterized macro, but as far as I could get things to work, it doesn't work with a variable argument, which appears to be required to be a hard-coded value - the syntax requires enclosing the "macro name" with single quotes, adding a space before the argument, like this:

```
'Test "test"'
```

Correctly invokes this macro:

```
Public Sub Test(ByVal value As String)
    MsgBox value
End Sub
```

But, if a macro needs to use data that exists on the worksheet at the time of invocation, there's no need to parameterize it. And if a macro needs to prompt the user for a date, a path, or anything, ...then it can absolutely do that.

Note that the date picker control will likely not work properly on a 64-bit host: Consider using [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54650417/1188513) to prompt the user for a date, that doesn't involve 32-bit ActiveX tech.

Comment: Anyway, 'Test "test"' results in file corrupted on restart if file is xlsb.