# Use Outlook ribbon button name as string in a macro

Tags: vba, outlook, ribbonx, microsoft365, custom-ui

I'm trying to get the `name` of a clicked button on the "Developer" Tab on the ribbon to use as a string in a macro in Outlook version 2212 with M365.

[image]

```vb
Sub ButtonNameDisplay()
Dim ButtonText As String
ButtonText = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
MsgBox (ButtonText)
End Sub
```

However, [ActiveSheet is only for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611434/2748772). And I couldn't get [the CommandBarButton.Caption property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarbutton.caption) to work either

```vb
ButtonText = Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBarButton.Caption
```

What can one set the `ButtonText` string value to so the message box displays the button name [`TestButtonName`] when clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the ribbon button instance (`IRibbonControl`) is passed as a parameter where you could get all the required information about the control (at least such as `Id`).

In the following code:

```
ButtonText = Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBarButton.Caption
```

The `Inspector` class doesn't provide the `CommandBarButton` property. To find the required control you need to use the [CommandBars.FindControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.findcontrols) method which gets the `CommandBarControls` collection that fits the specified criteria. You could use the `IRibbonControl.Id` value to find the control and get the caption property.

There are other techniques for getting information about the UI such as [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility), but that is too complex for VBA macros.

Anyway, command bars were deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer in Office add-ins for customizing the UI. Instead, the Fluent UI is used for creating a custom UI. Unfortunately Outlook doesn't allow customizing the UI from VBA macros like other host applications do, the best what you could do is to customize the QAT or move a button to the tab manually with a macro assigned to it. Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)